# Double MySQL Running on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php, mysql, osx-mountain-lion

After I've done a full restart, my Apache PHP server doesn't connect to Local MySQL ( connecting via 127.0.0.1 because localhost for some reason fails always ).

So I did this today:

```
➜  ~ mysqladmin shutdown -u root -p
Enter password:
➜  ~ mysqladmin shutdown -u root -p
Enter password:
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

Which basically means that I succeeded in shutting down mysql. But as soon as I did - Apache PHP successfully connect to MySQL and my local sites work without a hiccup until the next restart.

Here are a few other details:
(as you can tell - I've installed MySQL via `brew`)

```
➜  ~  sudo ps aux | grep mysql
N               4774   0.0  0.0  2432768    620 s000  S+    9:53AM   0:00.00 grep mysql
N               4772   0.0  2.6  3030168 440688   ??  S     9:51AM   0:00.29 /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13/lib/plugin --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --log-error=/usr/local/var/mysql/N.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/N.local.pid
N               4686   0.0  0.0  2433432   1000   ??  S     9:51AM   0:00.01 /bin/sh /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --bind-address=127.0.0.1
N               4362   0.0  2.7  3120276 458728   ??  S     9:47AM   0:00.45 mysqld


➜  ~  lsof -i | grep mysql
mysqld    4362    N   16u  IPv6 0x76959e40691f9f93      0t0    TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
```

This is the weird thing:

```
➜  ~  killall -9 mysqld
```

MySQL Is dead! Apache doesn't connect. Then, when I run:

```
➜  ~  sudo mysqladmin shutdown -u root -p
Enter password:
```

Apache is (again) able to successfully connect to MySQL.

As far as I understand this means that I have two mysql servers setup and both of them are trying to start up at the same time, but I don't have the slightest idea on how to fix it. I've tried brew reinstalling but that didn't help.

```
➜  ~  which mysqladmin
/usr/local/bin/mysqladmin
➜  ~  whence -p mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

## Solution:

**Step 1 from** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436425/how-do-you-uninstall-mysql-from-mac-os-x

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
vim /etc/hostconfig and removed the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking to see which launch daemons you've got setup in /Library/LaunchDaemons...I'm not sure what brew uses to configure startup items, but on Mac OS X, `launchd` is the current recommendation. If you find something related to MySQL in /Library/LaunchDaemons, you can unload it with a command similar to:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.plist
```

Previous versions (10.5;10.6) of Mac OS X included MySQL, which was installed into the /System/Library/LaunchDaemons folder:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

If you've installed versions of MySQL from Oracle/Sun, you may still have a MySQL StartupItem at /Library/StartupItems. It should be possible to stop that service like so:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM StopService
```

Outside of that, there shouldn't be many other places that you'd need to look...

Comment: Hey Eddie. No luck :( - I've updated my response listing out the Launch Daemons I could find.

I remember when installing MySQL I put the `homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` there myself from homebrew setup instructions - otherwise - I see no mysql daemons anywhere. Is there some other place I can look ?

Comment: Turns out I already fixed the issue. Editing my original post again.